# Using macro command in excel hides the correct lines

Tags: excel, vba

I have macros (one for each month) that jump to the correct row depending on the month. Now when I click on a month other than January, January is displayed (which is at the top of the list), but when I scroll with the mouse scroll wheel a few turns, the right part is scrolled forward. Also if I take Ctrl + end and then Ctrl + home, then the correct lines are displayed. This error is new - it has worked flawlessly until now for several years.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: "the right part is scrolled forward" not clear if right means "correct" or "on the right side"...   In either case, it's not clear what the problem is with no code and/or screenshot.